# Filemaker Pro Join Table records not created automatically

Tags: relational-database, filemaker

In filemaker pro 12

Tables:

- Department
- Instructor
- Training

Relationships:

- Department and Instructor: Many to many (sucks but an instructor can
  teach in 2 departments)
- Instructor and Training: Many to many

Both relationships have join tables with foreign key fields.

I'm trying to create a layout with subsummary parts.  First I wish to sort by Department.  Second by Training.  I'm sorting by department number (field of department) and eventName (field of event).  The sort displays the two subsummaries and actual works for department but for some reason event is not displaying.  Its subsummary can be seen but the values are empty.  How can I fix it?

Edit: I've narrowed it down to the Join table for Instructor and Training does not have any records.  Is there a reason why related tables wouldn't automatically be creating join table records?

Let me know if you have any further questions about my problem.  FMK frustrates me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect FileMaker to create records in join tables? FileMaker doesn't know which records to link, so you have to create some interface first. To do this you normally set up a relationship to the join table, check a flag to create records, and then add a portal for this relationship and enter some data. As spon as you set it up, it will work as expected. E.g. if this is a portal from Instructor to Instructor-Training table, then as soon as you select the Training ID in the portal row (with something like a pop-up menu), it will automatically fill in the Instructor ID.

Comment: So if I am importing large tables, the only way I can have it work is to write a script to fill in all the join tables?  I did this for a separate database but i thought it was a hacked way to do it

Comment: I'm not sure we understand each other. The join table isn't some magic table, right? It's a conventional word to indicate the role of the table. Physically it's a table with some data in it. If you have data for the join table, you can import it just as other tables. If you don't, then how FileMaker (or any other RDBMS) is supposed to create it without your help? How does it know which records from the *main* tables are supposed to have related records in the join table?